# Where is the WPF Timer control?

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

Where can I find a control which is like the C# Timer Control in WPF?

Answer (score 352, accepted):

The usual WPF timer is the `DispatcherTimer`, which is not a control but used in code. It basically works the same way like the WinForms timer:

```
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);
dispatcherTimer.Start();


private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // code goes here
}
```

More on the DispatcherTimer can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi, i've been trying to use dispatch timer but i cant find it in my intelisense is there any reference that needs to be added for me to use it?

Comment: I like the way you set the interval, better than milliseconds in my opinion.

Comment: Be sure to call dispatcherTimer.Stop() when you close your form.  The WinForms version of the timer does that automatically.  (That's the advantage of making the timer a Control.)  If you don't you'll have a memory leak and possibly other bugs.

Comment: @JL Eh? That code is impossible to interpret. Far better is `var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };`

Comment: In .NET 7.0 with VS 2022 I had to declare the timer function using nullable reference types like so.
`private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object? sender, EventArgs? e)`

Answer (score 12):

With Dispatcher you will need to include

```
using System.Windows.Threading;
```

Also note that if you right-click DispatcherTimer and click Resolve it should add the appropriate references.

Comment: need to add reference to WindowsBase.dll btw

Comment: IMHO this doesn't answer the question about which control to use, it merely adds some commentary to the accepted answer.

Comment: I added this in 2012, just really starting as a developer, I still get points for it. But as @StephenKennedy pointed out, this should be a comment.

Answer (score 3):

you can also use

```
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading;
```

Answer (score 0):

The timer has special functions.

1. Call an asynchronous timer or synchronous timer.
2. Change the time interval
3. Ability to cancel and resume

if you use `StartAsync ()` or `Start ()`, the thread does not block the user interface element

```
     namespace UITimer


     {
        using thread = System.Threading;
        public class Timer
        {

        public event Action<thread::SynchronizationContext> TaskAsyncTick;
        public event Action Tick;
        public event Action AsyncTick;
        public int Interval { get; set; } = 1;
        private bool canceled = false;
        private bool canceling = false;
        public async void Start()
        {
            while(true)
            {

                if (!canceled)
                {
                    if (!canceling)
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(Interval);
                        Tick.Invoke();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    canceled = false;
                    break;
                }
            }


        }
        public void Resume()
        {
            canceling = false;
        }
        public void Cancel()
        {
            canceling = true;
        }
        public async void StartAsyncTask(thread::SynchronizationContext 
        context)
        {

                while (true)
                {
                    if (!canceled)
                    {
                    if (!canceling)
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(Interval).ConfigureAwait(false);

                        TaskAsyncTick.Invoke(context);
                    }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        canceled = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

        }
        public void StartAsync()
        {
            thread::ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((x) =>
            {
                while (true)
                {

                    if (!canceled)
                    {
                        if (!canceling)
                        {
                            thread::Thread.Sleep(Interval);

                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(AsyncTick);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        canceled = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public void StartAsync(thread::SynchronizationContext context)
        {
            thread::ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((x) =>
            {
                while(true)
                 {

                    if (!canceled)
                    {
                        if (!canceling)
                        {
                            thread::Thread.Sleep(Interval);
                            context.Post((xfail) => { AsyncTick.Invoke(); }, null);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        canceled = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        public void Abort()
        {
            canceled = true;
        }
    }


     }
```

Comment: Can you explain your code? If you just post some code, people won't learn from it and just copy & paste some code from the web.